# ResourceSavingSceneView: Unexpected token (33:11) when running react-scripts start

Tags: react-navigation, react-native-web

I am using react-native-web with react-navigation 3.x.

Then I am running react-scripts start
a
and I have this error:

```html
./node_modules/@react-navigation/native/dist/ResourceSavingSceneView.js
SyntaxError: <path_to_my_app>/node_modules/@react-navigation/native/dist/ResourceSavingSceneView.js: Unexpected token (33:11)
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: Try upgrading to latest version.